# How get numbers and sum them in bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, split, numbers

I have an input file like this:

```
bread,5
water,15
butter,5
```

I want to write a script which will get the numbers from each line after the comma and add them. So the example output must be: 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk,

```
$ awk -F, '{c+=$2}END{print c}' file
25
```

Here `-F,` we are setting the Field Separator as comma. `{c+=$2}` would add every num exists on the second column to a variable called `c` . `c+=$2` is equal to `c = c + $2`. At the last `c` contains the total sum of all the numbers exists on the second column. Printing `c` in the END block will give the final value of `c` variable.

Comment: It works well, thank you!
Could you explain this line for me please?
c is a variable which store the price, the file should be the parameter file it is clear but how this code split by comma?

Comment: The -F option, "-F," indicates that the field separator is ","